# CakePHP Routing Problem

Tags: php, html, apache, cakephp, routes

I suffered a CakePHP Route Problem. I can only access the root "`/`" and it shows the CakePHP default welcome home page. Later I try to write my controller (icons_controller.php) and views (views/icons/index.ctp), it has problem. I typed in `http://localhost:8080/myapp/icons/` It always says "`Not Found The requested URL /myapp/icons/ was not found on this server.`" In my routers.php file it has:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

I create a controller in the icons_controller.php file like:

```
<?php
class IconsController extends AppController{
 var $name = 'Icons'; 
 function index() {
  $this->set('icons', $this->Icon->find('all'));
 }
}
?>
```

And it should simple open the file with only a paragraph tag text (in /views/icons/index.ctp)

```
<h1>My Icons</h1>
```

But I cannot open the index.ctp by using `localhost:8080/myapp/icons/`. So later I tried to modify my routers.php file like this, it works fine with the url `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'icons', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

It is fine and success display the "My Icons" text. Wondering why only works under "/", with anything else doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that you have mod_rewrite enabled on Apache.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: See also: http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess and http://book.cakephp.org/view/1533/A-Note-on-mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that you have not named the function the same as the route
display. So under controller you need a pages_controller with a display() {} function
as well as a display view in the pages folder under views.